# Two expressions to get an answer (If X = Y and A = B then the answer is D)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, dropdown, google-sheets-formula

Struggling on what should be a simple expression Google Sheets: Two expressions to get an answer (If X = Y and A = B then the answer is D)

You can see copy of the doc here. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ufFZfXQb0st4bWP_fcw50FKZSx-tRL58ELTClLsIMQs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine an `if` statement with an `and` operator, e.g.:

`=IF(AND(A13="BMW", B13="SUV"), B17, "Not defined")`

Answer (score 0):

you need nested `IF`:

```
=IF((A13="BMW") *(B13="SUV"),       B17, 
 IF((A13="Ford")*(B13="hatchback"), B20, ))
```

[image]